# simple worksheet loop and put cell value into vba array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to do a very simple program, but for some reason it is not working.
I want to loop through every worksheet in my workbook and get the cell value of O13 and put it in an array. then print the entire array in 1 worksheet. For some reason, it doesn't read in the number. I tried setting the array to variant, integer, and double, nothing works.

```
     Dim WS_Count As Integer

     Dim I As Integer

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     Dim array1(43) As Double

     For I = 1 To WS_Count

        array1(I) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Cells(13, 15).Value

     Next I

     Range("A40") = array1
```

Comment: What do you mean by **`it doesn't read in the number`** ?

Comment: You did notice you are reffering to `Cells(13, 15)` instead of `Cells(6, 15)` ?

Comment: @ManishChristian When I debug it says that array1(I) = 0 instead of the actual value

Comment: @ShaiRado I'm sorry, that was a typo on my end. I meant O13

Comment: Try `ReDim array1(1 To WS_Count)` and `Range(Cells(40, 1), Cells(40, 1 + WS_Count)) = array1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need start the array in 1 `Dim array1(1 to 43) As Double` and after set the range to put the array and use Transpose `Range("A40:A83") = Application.Transpose(array1)`

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfect. VBA is so complicated. I come from matlab. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

This works by me:

```
Public Sub SWL()

    Dim WS_Count    As Long
    Dim I           As Long
    Dim array1(43)  As String
    Dim str         As String

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For I = 1 To WS_Count

       array1(I) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Cells(1, 1).Value

    Next I

    str = CStr(Join(array1, " "))
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = str

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`WorksheetFunction.Transpose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196261.aspx) method to transpose the array into the range you wish to output into.

```
Range("A40:A83") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(array1)
```